# force ng-disabled and ng-show to reevaluation custom function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to validate a form with my custom js function "isValid". I did something like this:

```
<input id="pricecondition" name="pricecondition" ng-model="user.pricecondition" ng-focus="user.pricecondition=''" required />

<button ng-click="submit()" ng-disabled="form.$invalid && user.isValid">submit</button>
```

But it seems that the view ng-disabled calls user.isValid only once.

This is the js code of my controller:

```
$scope.user = {
    [...],
    lenght: "",
    pricecondition: "",
    isValid : function()
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

So when the property length or price condition changes the value the function isValid is fired, but the button seems not to re-evaluate user.isValid. The button is enabled obviously the function isValid returns false.

How can I force ng-disabled or ng-show to call isVlaid() again?

greetings

Comment: `ng-disabled="form.$invalid && user.isValid()"` try adding brackets after user.isValid given that its a function...

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I added the brackets to isValid() but it still didn't worked for me. I removed form.$invalid and now it works. ng-disabled="!user.isValid()". I dont' know why it isn't working with two statments like ng-disabled="form.$invalid && !user.isValid()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got another problem from your comment, sorry i didn't noticed that at first...
use formname and not tag name for disabling the button...

```
<form name="myform" novalidate >
    // your html
    <button ng-disabled="myform.$invalid">submit</button>
</form>
```

or if you have forms inside form then use ng-form

```
<form name="parentForm">
    <div ng-form="myform1">
        // your html
        <button ng-disabled="myform1.$invalid">submit1</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-form="myform2">
        // your html
        <button ng-disabled="myform2.$invalid">submit2</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have a form element with a name attribute in order to use "form.$invalid".
Also i would make the button invalid if the form is invalid OR the user is invalid.

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" name="form" novalidate >
  <input id="pricecondition" name="pricecondition" ng-model="user.pricecondition" ng-focus="user.pricecondition=''" required />
  <button ng-disabled="form.$invalid || !user.isValid()">submit</button>
</form>
```